# Find the Galois groups of the splitting field and their degree of $\mathbb{R}$ and $\mathbb{Q}$

Tags: field-theory, galois-theory

Let $p(x)=x^3-3x+3$. Find the Galois group of its splitting field if the ground field is

1. $\mathbb{R}$
2. $\mathbb{Q}$

First, note that by the Intermediate Value Theorem, we see that there is a real root $\alpha$ between $-2$ and $-3$. By some analysis, we know that there is one real root and two complex roots that are conjugates. Is it correct to say that the splitting field of this polynomial of $\mathbb{R}$ is a degree 2 splitting field, since we are only looking at the complex roots, and we know that we can square the complex numbers to make them real. Can we also say that the Galois group is isomorphic to $\mathbb{Z}_2$ using the splitting field over $\mathbb{R}$ is of degree 2 and the Fundamental theorem of Galois theory?

2. By Eisenstein's, we see the polynomial is irreducible over $\mathbb{Q}$. Again, let $\alpha$ be the real root. So we can say that $[\mathbb{Q}(\alpha, \mathbb{Q})]=3$. If $\beta$ is one of the complex roots, then we have $[\mathbb{Q}(\beta), \mathbb{Q}]$. So the splitting field of degree $6$. Since $S_3$ also has degree 6, we conclude that the Galois group of the splitting field over $\mathbb{Q}$ is isomorphic to $S_3$.

Could someone please check if my reasoning makes sense?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Basically OK, though it's not correct to say "we know that we can square the complex numbers to make them real". If the roots are $a,b\pm ic$ with $a,b,c$ real I'd argue that the splitting field is $\mathbb{R}[a,b+ic,b-ic]=\mathbb{R}[a,b,-ic]=\mathbb{R}[ic]=\mathbb{R}[i]=\mathbb{C}$ and then all is clear.

Comment: In part 2 the irreducibility of $p(x)$ implies that $[\Bbb{Q}(\beta):\Bbb{Q}]=3$. But in that step you are really interested in $[\Bbb{Q}(\alpha,\beta):\Bbb{Q}(\alpha)]$! Do you understand why? Do you see why that extension degree is exactly two, and, more importanyly, why it follows that the splitting field is a degree six extension?